# Using SUM in SQL Query with Filters

Tags: sql-server, sum

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I'm having a hard time with this query. Currently my query stands as follows:

```
SELECT  b.FOH_PMSCONFNUM,
        a.FOC_ACCOUNT,
        a.FOC_TCODE,
        a.[Net Amount]

FROM P5FOLIOHEADER b

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
        FOC_ACCOUNT, 
        FOC_TCODE, 
        SUM (FOC_NETAMOUNT) AS 'NetAmount'

FROM P5FOLIOCHARGE 

GROUP BY FOC_ACCOUNT,FOC_TCODE) a ON a.FOC_ACCOUNT = b.FOH_ACCOUNT
```

And the output is as follows:

```
 FOH_PMSCONFNUM   FOC_ACCOUNT  FOC_TCODE  NetAmount
    1216            52          ROOM       2500
    1216            52          ROOM       2500
    1216            52          ROOM       2500
    1216            52          DRINKS      900
    1216            52          DRINKS      600
    1301            75          ROOM       1800
    1301            75          ROOM       1800
    1653            90          ROOM       3000
    1653            90          TELEX       150
```

I need my output to be like this:

```
FOH_PMSCONFNUM   FOC_ACCOUNT  NetAmount(Room)  NetAmount(Drinks)  NetAmount(Telex)
    1216              52           7500             1500             0
    1301              75           3600               0              0
    1653              90           3000               0            150
```

Is there a way to write this query without using the PIVOT syntax? I will need to ultimately append this query to another query.

Ideally, I'm looking for a query where I can modify this part in my existing query: SUM (FOC_NETAMOUNT) AS 'NetAmount' and make it into something like this:

```
SUM (FOC_NETAMOUNT) AS 'NetAmount(Room)' WHERE FOC_tcode ='ROOM'
SUM (FOC_NETAMOUNT) AS 'NetAmount(Drinks)' WHERE FOC_tcode ='DRINKS'
SUM (FOC_NETAMOUNT) AS 'NetAmount(Telex)' WHERE FOC_tcode ='TELEX'
```

It is just that I'm stuck as how to write the logic in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression in the `sum` to filter out the values:

```
select
  b.FOH_PMSCONFNUM,
  a.FOC_ACCOUNT,
  a.FOC_TCODE,
  sum(case a.FOC_TCODE when 'ROOM' then a.[Net Amount] else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(Room)',
  sum(case a.FOC_TCODE when 'DRINKS' then a.[Net Amount] else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(Drinks)',
  sum(case a.FOC_TCODE when 'TELEX' then a.[Net Amount] else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(Telex)',
from
  P5FOLIOHEADER b
  left join P5FOLIOCHARGE a on a.FOC_ACCOUNT = b.FOH_ACCOUNT
group by
  a.FOC_ACCOUNT
```

Comment: isn't `b.FOH_PMSCONFNUM` missing in your group by?

Comment: @Guffa Thanks, I think you have a few brackets missing in the SUM statements. I did take it into account but it is not grouping correctly.

Comment: @user3115933: Yes, you are right, there were parentheses missing for the end of the `sum` calls. The grouping should of course only be on `FOC_ACCOUNT` when it groups the entire result. I corrected the code.

Comment: @Guffa Sorry to get back late on this! I get the following error message"
"Column 'P5FOLIOHEADER.FOH_PMSCONFNUM' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."